# Single tab multiple views

Tags: android

Can someone throw more light on how can one have multiple views within the same tab? I have 3 tabs.
I have used a FragmentActivity to load the content of the 1st tab, which is a ListFragment. On click of any item of the list another list of subItems must get displayed. To do this I am using an inner static FragmentActivity class, which in turn adds a new fragment dynamically which displays the new list. But In the new Fragment I do not get to see my 1st tab.

How can I switch between Fragments or Views keeping my Tab intact?

---

Still not able to achieve it...my code is as given below:

```
       public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) 
    {           
        getListView().setItemChecked(position, true);

        DetailsFragment details = (DetailsFragment)
                getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.titles);

        if (details == null || details.getShownIndex() != position) 
        {               
            details = DetailsFragment.newInstance(position);                
            FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.titles, details);
            ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
            ft.commit();
        }
   }
```

The layout file is as below:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?

<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:layout_width="match_parent" 
         android:layout_height="match_parent">

   <fragment class="com.example.myapp.NewReqScrLoader$TitlesFragment"
          android:id="@+id/titles"
          android:layout_width="match_parent" 
          android:layout_height="match_parent" /> 

</FrameLayout>
```

Am I going wrong somewhere?

Comment: I'm not sure of ListFragment.But i hope ur requirement is met with https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator

Answer (score 1):

You should replace the first ListFragment which another List FRagment built using the sub-items. Don't create a new FragmentActivity.

Use transaction.replaceFragment(..) to do this.

Comment: Tried doing this:                                                    FragmentTransaction ft = this.getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
          ft.replace(R.id.titles, details);   Here R.id.titles is added in the layout whereas details is a dynamic fragment. Is it the right thing to do? I am getting - IllegalArgumentException : No view found for id.